# ANDROID -PHP-JSON not getting data from server

Tags: php, android, json

hi i am new to android json...here i m sending the id to my php server for getting the data from database but not getting any value.plz help
here when i click the button it will go to next activity and taking the id also for the next activity...
this is my main activity...

```
package com.example.mydata;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4;

private static final String TAG_BID = "Id";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      tab1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tab1);
        tab1.setOnClickListener(this);
        tab2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tab2);
        tab2.setOnClickListener(this);
        tab3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tab3);
        tab3.setOnClickListener(this);
        tab4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tab4);
        tab4.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.tab1:     
        String id = "1";

        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Table1Activity.class);
        //startActivity(i);

        i.putExtra(TAG_BID, id);

        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);

        break;
    case R.id.tab2:

        break;
    case R.id.tab3:

        break;
    case R.id.tab4:

        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

   }
  }
```

here is my json file..

```
package com.example.mydata;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

    public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

    }
 }
```

here is my next activity

```
public class Table1Activity extends Activity {

TextView txtName;
TextView txtPrice;
TextView txtDesc;

String id;
JSONObject product;

//String Id;
//JSONObject product;
//String doc;


// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product us-book/Get_product_details.php
private static final String url = "http://app-developments.com/Jasmita/Address-book/Get_product_details.php";



// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_USER = "Address_Book";
private static final String TAG_ID = "Id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "Address";

      // JSONArray user = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table1);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "welcome", 3000).show();


    //new GetProductDetails().execute();

      Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    id = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();


    // Getting complete product details in background thread


    // save button click event


    // Delete button click event





}
/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */

class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Table1Activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url, "GET", params);
                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single book Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_USER); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID1);
                        txtPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
                        txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add1);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_ID));
                        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_EMAIL));


                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
           /*

          /**
          * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
          * **/
                  protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
             pDialog.dismiss();
               }
                }
                  }
```

here is my php code

```
  <?php

   $response = array();


  require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect1.php';

          // connecting to db
           $db = new DB_CONNECT();


            // get all products from products table
                  if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
                              $id = $_GET['id'];
               // get a product from products table
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Address_Book WHERE Id =$id ");

     if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $Address_Book = array();
        $Address_Book["id"] = $row["id"];
         $Address_Book["Name"] = $row["Name"];
          $Address_Book["Address"] = $row["Address"];

        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["Address_Book"] = array();

        array_push($response["Address_Book"], $Address_Book);

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
            } else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
             } else {
     // required field is missing
     $response["success"] = 0;
     $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

     // echoing JSON response
     echo json_encode($response);
          }
               ?>
```

Comment: are you getting data from php on a web browser?

Comment: what is the log value showing ? i mean for this `Log.d("Single book Details", json.toString());`

Comment: yes php file is  fine the required field is missing this is showing in server side coz first thet shud get the id